# Recognizing linear or polarized light and seeing its direction

Tags: visible-light, polarization

I watched [Walter Lewin's course](https://youtu.be/nFtNCPUMoYA?t=1h9m48s), and he said he learned how to see and recognize polarized or linear light. And I wonder what it might be. What are the tricks?

Comment: I don't know. This may be what he is talking about or may not bem, probably it is, though.

Comment: @CuriousOne that's a good answer right there...

Comment: @DanielGriscom: I didn't watch the video and I didn't know about the phenomenon until twenty minutes ago. Google and Wikipedia need to get the credit. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne Well, unless Google and/or Wikipedia will write the answer, then it seems like the task might fall to you ;)

Comment: @DanielGriscom: There you go. I hope someone can write a better answer, still, and maybe say something about other mechanisms employed by nature (insect and bird vision) to use polarized light.

Comment: @CuriousOne Of course, I push you to enter your answer, and then I gotta stick my oar in and edit it...

Comment: @DanielGriscom: You are more than welcome to make it better any which way you see fit.

Comment: [possible duplicate here?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88837/difference-in-perception-of-unpolarized-and-polarized-light)

Comment: @fpdx Actually, the answer here is the exact opposite of the other question's accepted answer. My guess is that this answer is more correct. How would we merge the two?

Comment: @Daniel Griscom True but the 2nd answer there (with more votes) is about the Haidinger's brush as here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the phenomenon of [Haidinger's brush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haidinger%27s_brush)? Thanks for pointing this out. I have seen this myself, but always thought that it was a flaw in my own vision. I didn't know it was a common phenomenon explainable by polarization.